# using swift and obj c both

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I've read this question: [How to call Objective-C code from Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002369/how-to-call-objective-c-code-from-swift]Link)[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002369/how-to-call-objective-c-code-from-swift). But I can found what I need.
I'm using swift like first language in my project and later I've add Objective C. But my problem is in Objective c file how I can call a function in swift, now I can do only the contrary (working in swift and using objective c class).
When I following code :

`#import "ViewController-Swift.h"`

xcode issues is that: `file not found.`

That's my problem now:

```
@objc class ShareViewController: UIViewController {
    var name: String
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }

    // Needed to add a class level initializer
    class func newInstanceNamed(name: String) -> ShareViewController {
        return ShareViewController(name: name)
    }

    func abilitaTimer(){
        println("ciao")

        }


    }
}
```

xcode issues is that: `required initializer init coder...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless the project you are building is called `ViewController`, then you have the wrong file name.  Look at the bridging header file that was created for you.  If it is called `xyzzy-Bridging-Header.h`, then the file you want to import in Objective-C is `xyzzy-Swift.h`.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift migrate in Objc-based project:**

- Create new `*.swift` file (in Xcode) or add it by using Finder
- Add `swift bridging empty header` if Xcode have not done this before (see 4 below)
- Implement your Swift class by using `@objc` attribute:

  `import UIKit
      @objc class Hello {
          func sayHello () {
              println("Hi there!")
          }
      }`
- Open **Build Settings** and check following parameters:
      **Product Module Name** : myproject
      **Defines Module** : YES
      **Embedded Content Contains Swift** : YES
      **Install Objective-C Compatibility Header** : YES
      **Objective-C Bridging Header** : $(SRCROOT)/Sources/SwiftBridging.h
- Import header (which is auto generated by Xcode) in your *.m file. Ex Suppose your project name is `myproject` then that file will be `myproject-Swift.h`.

  `#import "myproject-Swift.h"`
- Clean and rebuild your Xcode project

Comment: FYI: No need to add @objc if you are inheriting your swift class from any Objective-C class. Compiler will automatically do that for you